# Menu para selecionar cor

Tags: html5, aplicação-web

Estou fazendo uma ferramenta, e preciso de um menu para seleção de cor. 
Alguém poderia me dizer como fazer?
Algo semelhante a isso:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Com HTML5 simplesmente use `input` tipo *color*:

```html
Escolha a cor: <input type="color">
```

<sub>Observação: nem todos os *browsers* suportam esse tipo de *input*.</sub>

Ou então usar um *plugin* Javascript, como o http://jscolor.com/

Comment: Obrigado, era tudo que eu precisava.  
Não conhecia esse type color rsrs.

Comment: @Superbomber tenha em mente que nem todos os browsers suportam esse tipo de input, [ver aqui](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-color).

Answer (score 3):

Este picker da imagem em particular <strike>é o</strike> me parece ser o [Spectrum](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/). Com ele, basta fazer a inclusão dos arquivos

```
<script src='spectrum.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='spectrum.css' />
```

e fazer a chamada como um plugin jQuery no seu seletor, algo como:

```
$("#custom").spectrum({
    color: "#f00"
});
```

Comment: Inspect Element do Mozilla